# How do I run TypeScript files directly without generating any JavaScript files?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, you'd use the following command to enter watch mode:

```
tsc -w -p .
```

Then when `tsc` does detect a change, it'll transpile the `.ts` files and generate `.js` files.

This means that you can run the new JavaScript files using:

```
node example.js
```

I'd like to run TypeScript files directly, without having to use `node example.js`, how can I do this?

Comment: Why you don't want to run typescript by `node example.js`?

Answer (score 18):

> will run typescript without node example.js command How can I do it

You can use ts-node to compile + run directly (without ever writing to disk):

```
ts-node example.ts
```

## More

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node

Comment: It's a good tool to compile typescript without generating js file. Are there any tools that specified in the official microsoft? – user3736174 5 mins ago

Comment: how do I delete a message after run? 
message : "Watching build tasks has finished."

Answer (score 5):

After doing npm init, install these packages.

```
npm install -g ts-node typescript '@types/node'
```

Then run your files as

```
ts-node example.ts
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the basarat's answer.

Comment: I have added the necessary packages installation step also. With the other answer, devs might not know ts-node is a npm package and they have to install it before running that command.

Comment: The other answer is linking to the repo on GitHub, which is IMO better because it has more information and won't become outdated when the project changes. If you want to add some details to an answer, you could suggest an edit instead of posting a new one :)

Comment: I'm aligned on your point. Thanks!

Comment: @PavneetKaur don't listen to him, link answers are generally frowned upon, your answer is better even if it is a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

I fond `tsx` may be a better alternative for `ts-node`.

I have not researched about it deeply enough, but after severl cases, where `ts-node` couldn't work while `tsx` could work as expected with no manual configuration, I'm totally using `tsx` now , like:

```bash
npx tsx ./script.ts
```

More info : [tsx readme](https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx#readme)

Besides, it looks like `tsx` use `esbuild` to have a better speed.